# What is the best way to back up an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, backup, icloud

How is it recommended I back up my Xcode projects? Is there a way to backup the whole thing to the web to be pulled from in case the files are somehow deleted from my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which is the "best", it must surely depend on your budget, development environment, resources, time, etc etc. Here some ideas, I list them in the order of preference, starting with the FREE.

1. "Git" in effect creates a backup, even if strictly speaking its version control tool.
2. You can create and save it on your iCloud Drive, Google Drive, Sky Drive, etc etc, of course you need to manually duplicate it on a regular basis.
3. You can for sure get commercial tools to do this, do a google/wikipedia search, read some reviews.
4. "Time machine" perhaps overkill, although maybe you can tweek it to focus on your projects.
5. "rdist" is UNIX utility that you could setup in a "crontab" to do regular copies of files that changed, although a risky strategy.
6. Just use Finder to manually duplicate the entire folder, you just need to remember to do it.

Comment: When you say I can create and save it to google drive etc, would I be able to then open my google drive and download it on a separate computer and start working on it again? In other words, is this "creation" able to be opened from any Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried it but in theory you could. But take care you need to be careful not to open it in two places @ the same time since I am sure Xcode doesn't do any sort of record/file locking.

Comment: so when you say "create and save", what exactly do you mean? Where do I find this function?

Comment: You start a new project, third box in you need to tell it where you want to save it, choose your iCloud drive, or google one etc etc.

Comment: a new project? I can't save an existing one?

Comment: Yes, you could save an existing one too.